# Error: (E107) bind interface to port failed: interface already bound to port: port 'MC8051_ALU().AM.port_27' (sc_in)

Tags: c++, systemc

hello I am new to systemc. I am assigned a task of connecting all lower modules of alu of 8051(ie addsub,mutliplier,divider). I have written code which is compiling without any error but when i run object file I get the following error 
**Error: (E107) bind interface to port failed: interface already bound to port: port 'MC8051_ALU().AM.port_27' (sc_in)**

this is **mc8051_alu().cpp** file

```
#include "systemc.h"
#include <alumux.h>
#include <addsub_core.h>
#include <comb_mltplr.h>
#include <comb_divider.h>
#include <dcml_adjust.h>

SC_MODULE(mc8051_alu) {
//inputs of the block
sc_in< sc_bv<8> > rom_data_i,ram_data_i,acc_i;
sc_in< sc_bv<6> > cmd_i;
sc_in< sc_bv<2> > cy_i;
sc_in< sc_bv<1> > ov_i; 
//outs of th block 
sc_out< sc_bv<1> > new_ov_o; 
sc_out< sc_bv<2> > new_cy_o;
sc_out< sc_bv<8> > result_a_o,result_b_o;
//making an instance of every block 

//intrtnal signal of the block to connect the units alumux, addsub_core, alucore,_comb_mltplr,comb_divider and decimal_adjust together.
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_alu_result;
sc_signal< sc_bv<2> > s_alu_new_cy;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_alu_op_a;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_alu_op_b;
sc_signal< sc_bv<4> > s_alu_cmd;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_dvdnd;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_dvsor;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_qutnt;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_rmndr;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_mltplcnd;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_mltplctr;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_product;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_dcml_data;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_dcml_rslt;
sc_signal< sc_bv<1> > s_dcml_cy;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_addsub_rslt;
sc_signal< sc_bv<2> > s_addsub_newcy;
sc_signal< sc_bv<1> > s_addsub_ov;
sc_signal< sc_bv<1> > s_addsub_cy;
sc_signal< sc_bv<1> > s_addsub;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_addsub_opa;
sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > s_addsub_opb;
//constructor of the module
SC_CTOR(mc8051_alu) 
{
// connecting alumux inputs and outputs 

  alumux am("AM");
  addsub_core asc("ASC");
  comb_mltplr cm("CM");
  comb_divider cd("CD");
  dcml_adjust da("DA");

  am.rom_data_i(rom_data_i);
  am.ram_data_i(ram_data_i);
  am.acc_i(acc_i);
  am.cmd_i(cmd_i);
  am.cy_i(cy_i);
  am.ov_i(ov_i);
  am.cy_o(new_cy_o);
  am.ov_o(new_ov_o);
  am.result_a_o(s_addsub_opa);
  am.result_b_o(result_b_o);
  am.result_i(s_alu_result);
  am.new_cy_i(s_alu_new_cy);
  am.addsub_rslt_i(s_addsub_rslt);
  am.addsub_cy_i(s_addsub_newcy);
  am.addsub_ov_i(s_addsub_ov);
  am.op_a_o(s_alu_op_a);
  am.op_b_o(s_alu_op_b);
  am.alu_cmd_o(s_alu_cmd);
  am.opa_o(s_addsub_opa);
  am.opb_o(s_addsub_opb);
  am.addsub_o(s_addsub);
  am.addsub_cy_o(s_addsub_cy);
  am.addsub_ov_i(s_addsub_ov);
  am.dvdnd_o(s_dvdnd);
  am.dvsor_o(s_dvsor);
  am.qutnt_i(s_qutnt);
  am.rmndr_i(s_rmndr);
  am.mltplcnd_o(s_mltplcnd);
  am.mltplctr_o(s_mltplctr);
  am.product_i(s_product);
  am.dcml_data_o(s_dcml_data);
  am.dcml_data_i(s_dcml_rslt);
  am.dcml_cy_i(s_dcml_cy); 

// connecting alucore inputs and outputs 
 // ac.op_a_i(s_alu_op_a);
 // ac.op_b_i(s_alu_op_b);
 // ac.alu_cmd_i(s_alu_cmd);
 // ac.cy_i(cy_i);
 // ac.cy_o(s_alu_new_cy);
 // ac.result_o(s_alu_result);

// connecting addsub_core inputs and outputs 
  asc.opa_i(result_a_o);
  asc.opb_i(s_addsub_opb);
  asc.addsub_i(s_addsub);
  asc.cy_i(s_addsub_cy);
  asc.cy_o(s_addsub_newcy);
  asc.ov_o(s_addsub_ov);
  asc.result_o(s_addsub_rslt);
// connecting comb_mltplr inputs and outputs 
  cm.mltplcnd_i(s_mltplcnd);
  cm.mltplctr_i(s_mltplctr);
  cm.product_o(s_product);
// connecting comb_divider inputs and outputs 
  cd.dvdnd_i(s_dvdnd);
  cd.dvsor_i(s_dvsor);
  cd.qutnt_o(s_qutnt);
  cd.rmndr_o(s_rmndr);
// connecting dcml_adjust inputs and outputs 
  da.data_i(s_dcml_data);
  da.cy_i(cy_i);
  da.data_o(s_dcml_rslt);
  da.cy_o(s_dcml_cy);
}
};
```

now when i want to run this by writing a testbench in main function  i am getting above error

this is my **main.cpp** file

```
 #include "systemc.h"
#include "mc8051_alu().cpp"
//#include "stim.h"

int sc_main (int argc, char* argv[]) {


        sc_signal< sc_bv<6> > cmd_i; //= sc_uint<8>(1);
    sc_signal< sc_bv<8> > result_a_o,result_b_o,rom_data_i,ram_data_i,acc_i;

        sc_signal< sc_bv<2> > cy_i,new_cy_o;
        sc_signal< sc_bv<1> > ov_i,new_ov_o;
 mc8051_alu DUT("MC8051_ALU()");(//LINE WHERE ERROR IS COMING)
DUT.rom_data_i(rom_data_i);
DUT.ram_data_i(ram_data_i);
DUT.acc_i(acc_i);
DUT.cmd_i(cmd_i);
DUT.ov_i(ov_i);
DUT.cy_i(cy_i);
DUT.new_ov_o(new_ov_o);
DUT.new_cy_o(new_cy_o);
DUT.result_a_o(result_a_o);
DUT.result_b_o(result_b_o);

cmd_i= 0b010101;
sc_start(sc_time(1,SC_NS));

cout << "this is here"<< endl;
cout << cmd_i<< endl;

sc_stop();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to name all your objects especially your ports and signals, so that error messages make more sense by directly pointing to the relevant object. Do that in the module constructor initialization list.

Without all code its difficult to say, but most certainly your error is from "am.addsub_ov_i(s_addsub_ov);". You have that line twice in your constructor.